# How to set up the new mod_pagespeed method of Google?

Tags: apache, optimization, performance

Google published new methods for website optimizing. It's called "mod_pagespeed".

I have an Apache server and I do not understand what I should do to install the new feature of Google.

How can I set it up?

Comment: The first hit when Googling "mod_pagespeed":   http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html

Answer (score 0):

As already said, your first starting point should be [mod_pagespeed's home page](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) which on a quick glance looks very good and well-documented.

Other than that, "how to set up" is an extremely broad question. As `mod_pagespeed`s portal page says, page optimization is a complex issue. You best get started with that documentation is there, and come back when you have specific questions about how to implement something.

Comment: hi,i read further about the mod_pagespeed, i wanted to know about the setup, according to this url:http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html , wo can i install it on my apache server.thanks.